# Bulk update all kubernetes deployment API version

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using `apiversion : apps/v1beta2`in most of deployment however Kubernetes cluster version `1.14` it's recommended to use `apiversion : apps/v1`. Also v1beta2 will be deprecated from `Kubernetes 1.16`.

Is there any better option to reduce manual work and update all deployment which having version `apps/v1beta2` to `v1`.

Or I can use `patch` all deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before you apply any changes please make sure that they include any necessary changes to suit the `1.16` version.**

Some of the changes are:

> Deployment in the **extensions/v1beta1**, **apps/v1beta1**, and **apps/v1beta2** API versions is no longer served
>
> - Migrate to use the  **apps/v1**  API version, available since v1.9. Existing persisted data can be retrieved/updated via the new version.
> - Notable changes:
>
>   - `spec.rollbackTo`  is removed
>   - `spec.selector`  is now required and immutable after creation; use the existing template labels as the selector for seamless upgrades
>   - `spec.progressDeadlineSeconds`  now defaults to  `600`  seconds (the default in  `extensions/v1beta1`  was no deadline)
>   - `spec.revisionHistoryLimit`  now defaults to  `10`  (the default in  `apps/v1beta1`  was  `2`, the default in  `extensions/v1beta1`  was to retain all)
>   - `maxSurge`  and  `maxUnavailable`  now default to  `25%`  (the default in  `extensions/v1beta1`  was  `1`)
>
> --  *[Kubernetes.io: API deprecations in 1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/)*

Please refer to above link to check aforementioned necessary changes.

---

### `kubectl patch`

There is an official documentation about it: [Kubernetes.io: update api object kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)

Unfortunately the `kubectl patch` did change the `YAML` definition from the example but it was unable to change the `apiVersion`.

---

### `kubectl convert`

There is a tool built into `kubectl` named `kubectl convert` which converts existing `YAML` to suit the `1.16` version. **Please take in mind that it will be deprecated soon.** Take a look at the article about it: [Medium.com: Kubectl convert update api versions automatically](https://medium.com/star-systems-labs/kubectl-convert-update-api-versions-automatically-e669add17e3d)

---

### shell script

You could also write a script with the language of your choosing that will change:

- `apiVersion: apps/v1beta2`
- `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1`

to:

- `apiVersion: apps/v1`

---

You could also take a look on: [Github.com: Kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize)

Please let me know if you have any questions to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using move2kube (https://github.com/konveyor/move2kube) tool to achieve the above.

To achieve the above, do the following:

Create a yaml file that defines your cluster kinds like below (call is say clusterconfig.yaml):

```
apiVersion: move2kube.konveyor.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterMetadata
metadata: 
  name: Kubernetes
spec:
  storageClasses:
  - default
  - ibmc-block-bronze
  - ibmc-block-custom
  - ibmc-block-gold
  - ibmc-block-retain-bronze
  - ibmc-block-retain-custom
  - ibmc-block-retain-gold
  - ibmc-block-retain-silver
  - ibmc-block-silver
  - ibmc-file-bronze
  - ibmc-file-bronze-gid
  - ibmc-file-custom
  - ibmc-file-gold
  - ibmc-file-gold-gid
  - ibmc-file-retain-bronze
  - ibmc-file-retain-custom
  - ibmc-file-retain-gold
  - ibmc-file-retain-silver
  - ibmc-file-silver
  - ibmc-file-silver-gid
  apiKindVersionMap:
    APIService:
      - apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
    Binding:
      - v1
    CSIDriver:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
    CSINode:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
    CatalogSource:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    CertificateSigningRequest:
      - certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ClusterImagePolicy:
      - securityenforcement.admission.cloud.ibm.com/v1beta1
    ClusterRole:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ClusterRoleBinding:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ClusterServiceVersion:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    ComponentStatus:
      - v1
    ConfigMap:
      - v1
    ControllerRevision:
      - apps/v1
    CronJob:
      - batch/v1beta1
      - batch/v2alpha1
    CustomResourceDefinition:
      - apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    DaemonSet:
      - apps/v1
    Deployment:
      - apps/v1
    EndpointSlice:
      - discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Endpoints:
      - v1
    Event:
      - events.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - v1
    HorizontalPodAutoscaler:
      - autoscaling/v1
      - autoscaling/v2beta1
      - autoscaling/v2beta2
    ImagePolicy:
      - securityenforcement.admission.cloud.ibm.com/v1beta1
    Ingress:
      - networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - extensions/v1beta1
    InstallPlan:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    Job:
      - batch/v1
    Lease:
      - coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - coordination.k8s.io/v1
    LimitRange:
      - v1
    LocalSubjectAccessReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    MutatingWebhookConfiguration:
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
    Namespace:
      - v1
    NetworkPolicy:
      - networking.k8s.io/v1
    Node:
      - v1
    OperatorGroup:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1
    PersistentVolume:
      - v1
    PersistentVolumeClaim:
      - v1
    Pod:
      - v1
    PodDisruptionBudget:
      - policy/v1beta1
    PodSecurityPolicy:
      - policy/v1beta1
    PodTemplate:
      - v1
    PriorityClass:
      - scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - scheduling.k8s.io/v1
    ReplicaSet:
      - apps/v1
    ReplicationController:
      - v1
    ResourceQuota:
      - v1
    Role:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    RoleBinding:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Secret:
      - v1
    SelfSubjectAccessReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    SelfSubjectRulesReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Service:
      - v1
    ServiceAccount:
      - v1
    StatefulSet:
      - apps/v1
    StorageClass:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
    SubjectAccessReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Subscription:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    TokenReview:
      - authentication.k8s.io/v1
      - authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ValidatingWebhookConfiguration:
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
    VolumeAttachment:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

and then run :

```
move2kube translate -s <folder containing your clusterconfig.yaml file and kubernetes yaml files>
```

The interactive tool will ask for the required info and do the translation.